# Why does this simple regex error occur?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I wanted to see if I could strip the `*x` from these elements without using `rstrip`. I tried the following:

`import re
import time
list = ["3*x", "2", "4*x", "1", "3*x", "0"]
new_list = []
for terms in list:
    new_list.extend(re.sub(r'$(\*x)','', terms))
    print new_list
    time.sleep(4)`

This logically makes sense, because every element that has the `*x` will end with it, so I used `$`. Yet I get output like:
`['3', '*', 'x', '2', '4', '*', 'x', '1', '3', '*', 'x', '0']`
But if I just take away the `$` from the above code, then I get the correct output:

`['3', '2', '4', '1', '3', '0']`

So why does the initial code, give such erroneous output?
I am fairly new to regex entirely, so try to be fairly basic.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` denotes the end of the string. You want to match `*x` that's at the end of the string, so you need to write `\*x$`.

Also, since strings are iterables, `l.extend('asd')` will essentially do `l.append('a'); l.append('s'); l.append('d')`. You probably want to use `append`, not `extend`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I remember I came to the realization that I was using `$` incorrectly and it worked when I did what you said. But now my question is, what happens when my code is run, even though `$` is being used incorrectly?

Comment: Credits to person Blender: when `$` in a regular expression is either literally `$`, or the end of the string if it is at the end of the expression.

Comment: @Brian Alright, but that still doesn't explain to me why I get that weird output. What does my regular expression mean?